# Netbeans 6.9.1 problem finding library on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, include, netbeans-6.9

I am on a time crunch, and I can't seem to get Netbeans (6.9.1) to find a library

I need to incorporate a memory allocator form [libcds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcds/), I have coded what I believe to be a correct incorporation of the ~/cds-0.8.0/cds/memory/michael/allocator.h file.

The problem I have is that in my Netbeans project, it can't find the library.
I have `#include <cds/memory/michael/allocator.h>`
but it says it can't find the file. I placed the cds folder next to my main.cpp file.
I also ran the "build-linux-ia64.sh" script in the build folder as well.

I have the boost library installed through apt-get command `sudo apt-get install libboost1.40-all`

Lastly I am runing UBUNTU (Latest build, fully up to date).

Here is a picture of my project settings as well.
[image]

Comment: We're all on a "time crunch". And I think you mean Ubuntu, not UBUNTO.

Comment: I got it working.... I was including cds, when i should have just been including cds-0.8.0/

Comment: Another problem I had was that the beautiful 6 core computer we have, that supports 64 bit os, and has a 64 bit sticker, has a 32 bit Ubunto install. Which explains why the 64 bit script wasn't working....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else wanting to use this library here is the general guide:

First Make Sure you know if your system is 32 bits or 64, do not assume, since it is a 6 core, 8gb of Memory beast that it is running 64, like i did.

1) In the cds-0.8.0/build/sample, copy the script that best suites your os (I have no suggestions for Mac users, as there is no script), and copy it to the build folder (one level up)

2) Run the Script, it may take a while, if it finishes quick check the log.

3) In netbeans u need to set the following configurations
C++ Compiler:
Include Directories: cds-0.8.0
Additional Options: -msse2 -fno-strict-aliasing

The Linker: 
Additional Library Directories: cds-0.8.0/bin/gcc-x86-linux-32
Libraries: cds-0.8.0/bin/.../libcds.so
Additional Options: -msse2 -fno-strict-aliasing -shared -fpic

Good Luck, this library has a lot of promise

Note this library is still giving me trouble, but it compiles with these steps

Comment: Could you accept your own answer in case someone else has this problem in the future?

Comment: I plan too, but I am still having issues with it...
When get errors when I run it...not event the first line of code which is a print statement is executed. I emailed the developer and I am waiting on that